# How to install Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server

I got the Ubuntu server [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server), but it downloaded as an ISO file, which after opening, I had no idea what to do with. There were no .exe or .msi files in the disk. I did a Google search, but some results said that a language selection should automatically appear, and some said I had to burn the ISO file, but I don't have a disk slot on my PC (Running Windows 8).
Does anybody know how this works?

Answer (score 1):

You download an .ISO and need to burn this to a DVD or an USB stick; depending on what your server has available. Then, with the DVD in the system you reboot it and it will start the installation where you end up with a "dual boot" system.

Or you install a virtual machine (VM) in Windows 8 (ie.VM Ware or virtualBox) and install Ubuntu from within the VM.

Mind you: if you want it as a dual boot you need to turn off BIOS settings like "fast boot" and need to shutdown W8 without using "hibernation".

> There were no .exe or .msi files in the disk

Why would a Linux installation be an .exe or .msi? Those are Windows extensions.

Comment: OK, so i can burn it onto a USB drive? I have VMWare and VirtualBox, but I think that would be easier